# Cast result query mysql2 to type

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I had this class

```
export class User {

private username : string;
private first_name : string;
private last_name : string;
private birthdate : Date;
private gender : number;
private password : string;
private role_id : number;
private id : number | undefined; 

constructor(username : string, first_name : string, last_name : string, birthdate : Date, gender : number, password : string, role_id : number, id : number | undefined = undefined ){
         this.username = username
         this.first_name = first_name
         this.last_name = last_name
         this.birthdate = birthdate
         this.gender = gender
         this.password = password
         this.role_id = role_id
         this.id = id
    }
 }
```

I can save it in the DB through a function save(), but when I query my db to get an User, I would like to directly cast the result to a User object like a ORM does.

```
export async function getUsers(){
         const [result] = await conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>("SELECT * from users")
         return result
}
```

Thanks

I tried to create an interface IRowUser than extends RowDataPacket.

Comment: Why can't you map the row data into the User object inside that method and return that?  Casting does not feel right, because the relationship between the row cursor and your object is not IS-A.  Inheritance isn't correct in this case.

Comment: Like create a new user with the data ? Yes I can do that but I was looking for a more elegant way

Comment: Why is that not elegant?   At least it's correct.  Casting clearly isn't.

Comment: Yes you right, I don’t know because I probably use too much ORM where you can’t find the difference when you talk to the db, like transparency